# Why does this ThinkPad T440s intermittently refuse to power on?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, thinkpad, cmos

I press the power button on my ~2015 ThinkPad T440s and there is no effect whatsoever. The problem occurs regardless of whether the A/C adapter is connected and whether the removable battery is present. Moreover, disconnecting then reconnecting the A/C adapter does not cause the power button to flash as normal.

The issue has happened twice so far, two weeks apart. Both times, I have solved it temporarily by disconnecting then reconnecting both the CMOS battery and internal backup battery. Then I can boot as normal.

Other details that may be relevant:

- After doing the fix described, I can boot off the internal battery alone, even with CMOS battery, removable battery, and A/C power disconnected. So I know the internal battery is not entirely dead (though it may be on its way).
- Disconnecting/reconnecting the CMOS battery alone does not solve the problem. I have not tried disconnecting/reconnecting just the internal battery.
- The internal backup battery and CMOS battery are originals. The removable battery was replaced several months ago with a generic.

What are the possible causes for this problem, and what should I do to mitigate or further investigate it? I'd prefer not to buy a professional repair/assessment or expensive diagnostic tools.

Comment: The most likely cause is an intermittent power button or intermittent circuitry connected to it. It seems to me your temporary fixes are not related in any significant way to the power circuit. So repair assessment time.

Comment: What is the "external battery"? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc "Removable battery" or "main battery" might be the proper term for what I called "external battery." I'll update the post to clarify. It's the battery that can be removed without opening the laptop chassis.

Comment: Check contacts on the power button, it might be defective.